# Clarification for Vendors, and how to handle them

Tags: xcode, code-organization

So, i come across an XCode Project called [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) Framework, and I saw this Vendor Group in it...

So is Vendor just a way to organize some third party code? Is the term "Vendor" generic, or used with other Projects not only in Obj-C?

If so, how do you handle these third party codes when a time comes that they will be updated by the owner?